# Validating multiple sets of radio buttons

Tags: javascript, types, input

I have a form with 29 selections of radio button pairs, each with a Yes/No selection.

The names of the selections increment like this for each set: ans1, ans2, ans3... ans29.
Each one  have a value of "yes" or "no"

It follows more or less like this:

```
<input type="radio" id="yes1" name="ans1" value="yes"/>
<input type="radio" id="no1" name="ans1" value="no"/>
```

I want to write a Javascript function to validate the answers when submitting the form. I was thinking of using array's within a loop, but have no idea how to get the selections into an array.

The obvious long method is a repetitive `if(ans1 = yes) {do something} if(ans2=yes){do something}`.
I have seen examples of `getElementsByName` but is not sure how to implement it in a simple loop function to test for each and every iteration.

Comment: Have you tried using an object instead of an array?

Comment: How do you want to validate exactly?  What are the rules?

Answer (score 5):

**Using jQuery**

```
$("input:radio:checked").each(function (index) {
    var this$ = $(this);
    var q = this$.attr('name');
    var a = this$.val();

    console.log('Question: ' + q + ', answer: ' + a);
});
```

This snippet selects only checked radio buttons and then prints them to the console. You can do whatever you want from here, `q` is the name of the question (e.g. `ans1`) and `a` is the answer itself (i.e. `true` of `false`).

See it [in action](http://jsfiddle.net/VQJxU/1/).

Answer (score 1):

use jquery (http://jquery.com/) like

```
for(int i = 1; i < 30; ++i)
{
    if ($('#yes' + i).val() == 'yes'){ do something }
}
```